# Is it possible to obtain predictions in IOB format? - NER

Tags: spacy

When evaluating my NER models, I would like to pass my evaluation data to the predict method and get as output the predictions in IOB format.  The reason I want this is I need to use `seqeval` to obtain the confusion matrix as there is no such capability in spaCy.  Is this possible - to produce output compatible for use with `seqeval` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the IOB annotations with `token.ent_iob`:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
doc = nlp('John Young goes for a walk.')
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.ent_iob_)
```

which produces

> John B
>
> Young I
>
> goes O
>
> for O
>
> a O
>
> walk O
>
> . O

So then I think you should be able to use that to convert the predictions to the format you need?

[updated after the first 2 comments]

Comment: Ok thank you, it works, but only for sentences that contain one or more entities.  It doesn't output anything if there were no entities, in which case I probably would just get the tokens and assign them `O` myself.  Also it did not work at all when I tried `doc = nlp.make_doc(sentence)`

Comment: You're right, any token that has no `ent_iob_` annotation, can be considered `O`

Comment: @erotavlas: I updated the answer, it's actually better to just look at the tokens directly, and not `doc.ents`, then you include the `O` cases automatically.