# generate IOB1 tags for a sentence based on offset

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I have a list of sentences, I want to generate a list of [IOB2 tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside%E2%80%93outside%E2%80%93beginning_(tagging)) for each based on offset and length as input to [seqeval Hugging Face model](https://huggingface.co/spaces/evaluate-metric/seqeval).

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61080946/is-it-possible-to-obtain-predictions-in-iob-format-ner) with spacy entities, but that wouldn't take into account my existing tagging.
Also saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722146/pandas-split-sentence-and-label-phrases-to-perform-bio-tagging) but was wondering if there's a better way/some library to tag sentences of this sort.

input:

```
columns =  ['text', 'annotation.text',  'offset',   'length']
lst = [
    ['Johnny likes pizza and chocolate, he lives in Italy with Emily.', 'Johnny',   0,  6],
    ['Johnny likes pizza and chocolate, he lives in Italy with Emily.', 'pizza and chocolate',  13, 19],
    ['Johnny likes pizza and chocolate, he lives in Italy with Emily.', 'Italy',    46, 5],
    ['Johnny likes pizza and chocolate, he lives in Italy with Emily.', 'Emily.',   57, 6]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =columns)
df
```

desired output:

```
columns2 =  ['text',    'annotation.text',  'offset',   'length','IOB_LIST']
lst2 = [
    ['Johnny likes pizza and chocolate, he lives in Italy with Emily.', 'Johnny',   0,  6, ['B',    'O', 'O',   'O', 'O', 'O','O', 'O','O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']],
    ['Johnny likes pizza and chocolate, he lives in Italy with Emily.', 'pizza and chocolate',  13, 19, ['O',    'O', 'B',   'I', 'I', 'O','O', 'O','O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'] ],
    ['Johnny likes pizza and chocolate, he lives in Italy with Emily.', 'Italy',    46, 5, ['O',    'O', 'O',   'O', 'O', 'O','O', 'O','O', 'B', 'O', 'O', 'O']],
    ['Johnny likes pizza and chocolate, he lives in Italy with Emily.', 'Emily.',   57, 6, ['O',    'O', 'O',   'O', 'O', 'O','O', 'O','O', 'O', 'O', 'B', 'I']]
]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(lst2, columns =columns2)
df2
```

I thought maybe it's possible with spacy [entity recognizer](https://spacy.io/api/entityrecognizer) or nltk
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the perfect solution, but if anyone's running into this problem - I ended up using this tutorial -
https://lajavaness.medium.com/1-token-classification-vs-span-categorization-52a685e4674a

with roberta tokenizer and this function, I had to adjust my input and add another column with `{"start": ..., "end": ..., "tag": ...}` format, then it worked really great.

```
def get_token_role_in_span(token_start: int, token_end: int, span_start: int, span_end: int):
"""
Check if the token is inside a span.
Args:
  - token_start, token_end: Start and end offset of the token
  - span_start, span_end: Start and end of the span
Returns:
  - "B" if beginning
  - "I" if inner
  - "O" if outer
  - "N" if not valid token (like <SEP>, <CLS>, <UNK>)
"""
if token_end <= token_start:
    return "N"
if token_start < span_start or token_end > span_end:
    return "O"
if token_start > span_start:
    return "I"
else:
    return "B"


def tokenize_and_adjust_labels(sample):
    """
    Args:
        - sample (dict): {"id": "...", "text": "...", "tags": [{"start": ..., "end": ..., "tag": ...}, ...]
    Returns:
        - The tokenized version of `sample` and the labels of each token.
    """
    # Tokenize the text, keep the start and end positions of tokens with `return_offsets_mapping` option
    # Use max_length and truncation to ajust the text length
    tokenized = tokenizer(sample["text"], 
                          return_offsets_mapping=True, 
                          padding="max_length", 
                          max_length=MAX_LENGTH,
                          truncation=True)
    
    # We are doing a multilabel classification task at each token, we create a list of size len(label2id)=13 
    # for the 13 labels
    labels = [[0 for _ in label2id.keys()] for _ in range(MAX_LENGTH)]
    
    # Scan all the tokens and spans, assign 1 to the corresponding label if the token lies at the beginning
    # or inside the spans
    for (token_start, token_end), token_labels in zip(tokenized["offset_mapping"], labels):
        for span in sample["tags"]:
            role = get_token_role_in_span(token_start, token_end, span["start"], span["end"])
```